# How to tie Opportunity to Opportunity owner?

Tags: apex, trigger

My current flow looks like this: a `lead` is converted to an `account` and an `opportunity` is automatically created. I maintain ownership of the `Account` but manually assign the `opportunity` to another user. The problem I'm having is that when I assign the `Opportunity` to another user, their opportunity count doesn't change.

I have a formula that relies on the Opportunity count for each user being accurate and this issue is throwing that number off. I'm told that I can force the count to update when I assign this opportunity to a user using Apex, but am not very fluent in Apex.

Where would I start in trying to write this trigger?

By the way, I'm using both `Business` and `Person` `accounts`. The Users are setup on Business Accounts and the leads are converted to Person accounts.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you counting Opportunities?

Comment: you say that the Users are setup on Business Accounts, surely you mean Contacts, because Users are a different object. Are you counting opps in a report?

Comment: Sorry, I am using the partner portals so I refer to them as users when, yes, they are basically Account contacts. I count Opps using a rollup summary. The problem is that manually assigned Opps aren't populating on the Account Contact profile so the Rollup summary doesn't reflect the manually assigned Opps.

Comment: In speaking with Support, I was told the only way to accomplish this was to write an Apex trigger that would force the attachment of manually assigned Opps to the Opp owner.